# SQL SELECT MIN(time) where time is a string

Tags: sql, sqlite, time, min

I want to select the earliest time from a 'times' table where the 'time' column is a string formatted like this "%H:%M:%S" (ie. 13:30:00). I'm not sure how I would use the MIN() function in a select when it's a string not a time type. Please help!

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but I think that inside your MIN function you will need to do some other SELECT and convert string to time, maybe this will help: http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/  and this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: `MIN` can be used with strings.

Comment: yup, just realized that after posting this question, no conversion needed. Btw using SQLite. Thanks!

Comment: There could be a difficulty if the hour isn't zero-padded (e.g., `9:30:45`).

Comment: the hour, mins and seconds are all padded with zeros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use direct min or max

```
SELECT max(time) from t;

SELECT min(time) from t;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3aad3f